# Error when writing a recursive trait method with an associated type as an argument

Tags: generics, recursion, rust, traits, associated-types

I've been updating a library to use Rust's new associated types. The library offers a `Node` trait for constructing a DSP graph. Below is a simplified version of the trait that produces the same error I'm running into in my library.

```
use std::default::Default;
use std::num::Float;

trait Node {
    type Output: Default + Float;

    fn inputs<N>(&mut self) -> Vec<&mut N>
        where
            N: Node<Output = <Self as Node>::Output>;

    fn output_requested(&mut self, output: &mut <Self as Node>::Output) {
        for input in self.inputs().into_iter() {
            let mut working: <Self as Node>::Output = Default::default();
            input.output_requested(&mut working);
            //    ^~~~~ ERROR
            *output = *output + working;
        }
    }

}

fn main() {}
```

Here's the error message

```
<anon>:15:19: 15:49 error: the type of this value must be known in this context
<anon>:15             input.output_requested(&mut working);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Playpen link - http://is.gd/xm0wvS](http://is.gd/xm0wvS)

Considering that `self.inputs()` returns `N` where `N: Node<Output = <Self as Node>::Output>`, I'm under the impression rustc should have enough type information about `input` to satisfy the call to the `output_requested` method?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the problem is that the compiler has no way of determining the type of `N` in the call to `inputs`.  You've told it that it has to implement `Node`, but I can't see any way for it to work out an actual *concrete* type.  I tried adding an `N` parameter to `output_requested`, but then it can't unify the two different `Output`s this creates.  Honestly, without a more concrete idea of what you're trying to do, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: To further clarify: the problem I can't find a way around is convincing the compiler that the result of the addition is the same type as `*a`.  This is *much* easier to see if you change `type Output` to something else, say `type NodeOut`.  Then, the `Output` you see in the error is talking about `Add::Output`.

Comment: could it have something todo with object safety? http://is.gd/SFNNCM

Comment: @DK. Ahhh. First, to clarify, all inputs should have the same `Output` type as `Self`. I was under the impression that the `N: Node<Output = <Self as Node>::Output>` is equivalent to saying that `N`'s `Output` type must be the same as `Self`'s `Output` type (and considering that type is constrained by `Float` it should be fine to add and assign)? Perhaps what I'm really after is `where <N as Node>::Buffer = <Self as Node>::Buffer` which is still unimplemented?

 Btw, `output_requested` can be overridden to mutate the `output` arg in different ways, however by default it just sums all inputs.

Comment: @ker I don't think that's the case, as `self.inputs()` returns a vector of generic type `N: Node` (not trait objects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: given an object `x` implementing `Node`, `x.inputs()` takes a generic parameter `N` and returns `Vec<&mut N>`.

Now let’s write out a more explicitly typed version of what’s happening in `output_requested`.

(Incidentally, with the fancy new `IntoIterator` basis of the `for` loop, the `.into_iter()` is no longer necessary.)

```
fn output_requested(&mut self, output: &mut <Self as Node>::Output) {
    let inputs: Vec<&mut N> = self.inputs();
    for input in inputs {  // input: &mut N
        let mut working: <Self as Node>::Output = Default::default();
        input.output_requested(&mut working);
        *output = *output + working;
    }
}
```

Well, then; what can we figure about this type `N`? Can we resolve it?

- It came from `self.inputs()`, introducing the constraint that it implements `Node<Output = <Self as Node>::Output>`;
- On the object, you called the method `self.output_requested(&mut <Self as Node>::Output)`, which only confirms the previous point.

So all we know about this `N` is that it implements `Node` with the same `Output` as our type. But that could be two completely different types, like this:

```
impl Node for A {
    type Output = Out;
    …
}

impl Node for B {
    type Output = Out;
    …
}
```

Thus you can see that it is not possible to determine what `N` is; it can always be `Self`, but there may be other possibilities as well, and so it cannot be resolved statically and is forbidden.